# Create Oracle functions - how to reduce boilerplate code

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, boilerplate

I have two query statements, which are the very same, only the 3 columns are different I am using to create pivot tables. The first two gives the dimensions of the pivot while the third column has the data we call the aggregate function on.

I'm a newbie with SQL so I wonder if there is any clean way to define a function with the 3 column name parameters and a 4th parameter which gives the aggregate function.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT SDDCTO, SDSRP4, SDSOQS
  FROM MyTable
)
PIVOT (
  sum(SDSOQS)  
  for SDDCTO 
  IN ('EB' AS EB 
      'EL' AS EL, 
      'ER' AS ER, 
      'ES' AS ES, 
      'E1' AS E1, 
      'E2' AS E2, 
      'E5' AS E5 
      'E9' AS E9
      )
)
ORDER BY SDSRP4
;

-- Same query with different columns and aggregate function
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT SDDCTO, SDMCU, SDAEXP
  FROM MyTable
)
PIVOT (
  avg(SDAEXP)  
  for SDDCTO 
  IN ('EB' AS EB, 
      'EL' AS EL, 
      'ER' AS ER, 
      'ES' AS ES, 
      'E1' AS E1, 
      'E2' AS E2, 
      'E5' AS E5, 
      'E9' AS E9
      )
)
ORDER BY SDMCU
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For real world projects earlier you get comfortable with dyanmic SQL and functions in from clause - better in the long run.

I hate writing same or similar code twice.  So best option will be something like

```
select ...
from table(plsql_package ( parameters ))
```

Comment: What is the best angle, documentation or tutorial to start learning dynamic SQL in your opinion? It seems a bit hardcore at first sight to be honest.

Comment: Times have changed -- now execute immediate interface makes it quite simple.  So just look up documentation of execute immediate and build up from there.  Then see cursors for it.  You have a good project to build which makes it easier to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use a function, which would have to use dynamic SQL probably be more of a pain to maintain than the two separate queries; but you could create a view that combines both aggregates in one:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT SDDCTO, SDSRP4, SDSOQS, SDMCU, SDAEXP
  FROM MyTable
)
PIVOT (
  sum(SDSOQS) as SUM_SDOQS,
  avg(SDAEXP) as AVG_SDAEXP
  for SDDCTO 
  IN ('EB' AS EB, 
      'EL' AS EL, 
      'ER' AS ER, 
      'ES' AS ES, 
      'E1' AS E1, 
      'E2' AS E2, 
      'E5' AS E5, 
      'E9' AS E9
      )
)
;
```

... and then query the view in your two queries, instead of the table:

```
SELECT SDSRP4, EB_SUM_SDOQS, EL_SUM_SDOQS, ER_SUM_SDOQS, ES_SUM_SDOQS,
  E1_SUM_SDOQS, E2_SUM_SDOQS, E5_SUM_SDOQS, E9_SUM_SDOQS
FROM MyView
ORDER BY SDSRP4
;

SELECT SDMCU, EB_AVG_SDAEXP, EL_AVG_SDAEXP, ER_AVG_SDAEXP, ES_AVG_SDAEXP,
  E1_AVG_SDAEXP, E2_AVG_SDAEXP, E5_AVG_SDAEXP, E9_AVG_SDAEXP
FROM MyView
ORDER BY SDMCU
;
```

I'm not sure it gains you all that much though...

Comment: Well, I was lyinga bit to make the questions simpler. To be honest I'm using this code for the 11th time now, because I have a lot of columns to make pivots with.

Comment: You could add more aggregates to the pivot in the view, and more columns to the inner query; as long as they all need the same pivot 'in' and 'for' clauses. I think it's either that, or a (maybe pipelined) function using dynamic SQL; but someone else might come up with something I haven't though of, of course.